# Reproducing a ggplot2 geom_linerange() example

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a plot that will end up looking like this:

[image: geom_linerange() example]

However, I want the endpoints of each line to represent the 25th percentile (at the bottom) and 75th percentile (at the top) of each group of numbers. The dot in the middle should be the median. I can make box plots from these data with `geom_boxplot()`, but I think this would look a lot nicer. Anyway, I can't make this work. Right now I am getting this error message:

```
Warning message:
In data.frame(x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
```

My data look like this:

```
> str(outbtu)
'data.frame':   86400 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ bias: num  -0.248 -0.759 -0.471 -0.304 -0.358 ...
 $ cnd : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> outbtu[1:10,]
          bias cnd
1  -0.24756150   1
2  -0.75906264   1
3  -0.47142178   1
4  -0.30395184   1
5  -0.35756559   1
6   0.04072695   1
7  -0.45026249   1
8  -0.20509166   1
9  -0.24816174   1
10 -0.01581920   1
```

Where, eventually `cnd` reaches 27, but there are 3200 observations for each of the 27 `cnd` values, so you can't see it here obviously. I want 27 line segments on this graph, one corresponding to the 25th, 50th, and 75th percentile of the `bias` variable for each of the 27 `cnd` values.

Here is my code:

```
p <- ggplot(outbtu,aes(factor(cnd),bias,
                   ymin=quantile(bias,.25),
                   ymax=quantile(bias,.75)))
p <- p + geom_linerange()
p + geom_pointrange()
```

I honestly have no idea if I'm even close, that's just what I could figure out from the ggplot help pages. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(bias=rnorm(2700),cnd=1:27)
DF$cnd <- factor(DF$cnd)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF,aes(x=cnd,y=bias,colour=cnd)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=function(x) {
    res <- quantile(x,probs=c(0.25,0.5,0.75))
    names(res)<-c("ymin","y","ymax")
    res})
```

Or shorter:

```
ggplot(DF,aes(x=cnd,y=bias,colour=cnd)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=median_hilow,conf.int=0.5)
```

Comment: One point of clarification for me please -- I see that if I leave out `conf.int=0.5` from the shorter example you posted, the plot gets all screwed up. Is this really telling ggplot to plot confidence interval widths of 50%? I don't understand how this would mesh with the quartiles thing -- they seem like two totally different concepts -- is this doing something else?

Comment: From `?smean.sd` in package Hmisc (where `?median_hilow` points to): "For smedian.hilow, conf.int is the coverage probability the outer quantiles should target. When the default, 0.95, is used, the lower and upper quantiles computed are 0.025 and 0.975."

Comment: I see, so `conf.int=0.5` tells `median_hilow` to include the middle 50 percent of the distribution, which, when split between the two endpoints, ends up being the 25th percentile and the 75th percentile. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate all statistics separately and then draw obtained median and quantile values. Otherwise `ymin=quantile(bias,.25)` returns vector of bigger size than `factor(cnd)`.

Here is an example

```
# Generate sample data
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b=sample(1:5, 100, replace=T))
# Calculate statistics for each group of b values
df2 <- t(sapply(unique(df$b), function(x) {
  s <- summary(df[df$b == x, "a"])[c(2,3,5)]
  c(x, s)
}))
# Convert output matrix to data.frame since ggplot works only with data.frames
df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)
# Rename column names for clarity
colnames(df2) <- c("b", "Q1", "Median", "Q3")
# Draw obtained values
ggplot(df2, aes(x=b, y=Median, ymin=Q1, ymax=Q3)) + geom_pointrange()
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about separating the calculations from the plotting instructions. It will be helpful in the future for sure!